# Comment post scalability: Top n per user, 1 update, heavy read

Tags: database, scalability, message-queue

Here's the situation. Multi-million user website. Each user's page has a message section. Anyone can visit a user's page, where they can leave a message or view the last 100 messages.

Messages are short pieces of txt with some extra meta-data. Every message has to be stored permanently, the only thing that must be real-time quick is the message updates and reading (people use it as chat). A count of messages will be read very often to check for changes. Periodically, it's ok to archive off the old messages (those > 100), but they must be accessible.

Currently all in one big DB table, and contention between people reading the messages lists and sending more updates is becoming an issue.

If you had to re-architect the system, what storage mechanism / caching would you use? what kind of computer science learning can be used here? (eg collections, list access etc)

Comment: Hard to recommend an architectural solution without knowing your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general thoughts, not particular to any specific technology:

1. Partition the data by user ID. The idea is that you can uniformly divide the user space to distinct partitions of roughly the same size. You can use an appropriate hashing function to divide users across partitions. Ultimately, each partition belongs on a separate machine. However, even on different tables/databases on the same machine this will eliminate some of the contention. Partitioning limits contention, and opens the door to scaling "linearly" in the future. This helps with load distribution and scale-out too.
2. When picking a hashing function to partition the records, look for one that minimizes the number of records that will have to be moved should partitions be added/removed.
3. Like many other applications, we could assume the use of the service follows a power law curve: few of the user pages cause much of the traffic, followed by a long tail. A caching scheme can take advantage of that. The steeper the curve, the more effective caching will be. Given the short messages, if each page shows 100 messages, and each message is 100 bytes on average, you could fit about 100,000 top-pages in 1GB of RAM cache. Those cached pages could be written lazily to the database. Out of 10 Mil users, 100,000 is in the ballpark for making a difference.
4. Partition the web servers, possibly using the same hashing scheme. This lets you hold separate RAM caches without contention. The potential benefit is increasing the cache size as the number of users grows.
5. If appropriate for your environment, one approach for ensuring new messages are eventually written to the database is to place them in a persistent message queue, right after placing them in the RAM cache. The queue suffers no contention, and helps ensure messages are not lost upon machine failure.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution could be to denormalize your data, and store pre-calculated aggregates in a separate table, e.g. a MESSAGE_COUNTS table which has a column for the user ID and a column for their message count. When the main messages table is updated, then re-calculate the aggregate.

It's just shifting the bottleneck from one place to another, but it might move it somewhere that's less of a burden.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already use memcached incr/decr to store the counts. The issue is more in the contention amongst the updates/inserts.